# Confidence interval for mean of a uniform distribution

Tags: probability, distributions, confidence-interval, inference, uniform-distribution

I've been trying to compute a 95% confidence interval for the mean of a height sample, which is uniformly distributed. I have calculated the following sample statistics:

$$n=10 \quad \quad \bar{x} = 73.55 \quad \quad s = 1.68 \quad \quad s^2 = 2.83.$$

How can I calculate the CI of the mean of a uniform distribution not knowing the limits of the distribution?  I only know the CI for the normal distribution.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to calculate the confidence interval of?  The mean?

Comment: yes, I need the CI of the mean

Comment: Please register &/or merge your accounts (you can find information on how to do 
this in the **My Account** section of our [help]), then you will be able to 
edit & comment on your own question.

Comment: thank you for your answer, so, if generally speaking, to find CI for uniform distribution, i can use t test as i do in normal distribution?

Comment: How can i solve it without t-test?

Comment: @EfratBrayer please do not use answers for commenting and asking questions. Answers are meant for answering them. Moreover, if this is your question, then please merge your accounts as suggested by gung.

Comment: @EfratBrayer See updated answer.

Comment: Could you disclose the basis for assuming the sample is drawn from a truly uniform distribution?  The question needs a different answer if this is a conclusion drawn from examining the data or if it is an assumption based on logically independent information.

Answer (score 12):

A student-$t$ confidence interval is quite robust to deviations from normality.  If the data is uniformly distributed, the following simulation shows that the student-$t$ interval is slightly anti-conservative with a true confidence level around 0.947, for a nominal level of 0.95 and a sample size of $n=10$.

```
> a <- 0
> b <- 1
> mu <- (a+b)/2
> nsim <- 1e+5
> hits <- 0
> n <- 10
> for (i in 1:nsim) {
+   x <- runif(n, a, b)
+   ci <- confint(lm(x ~ 1))
+   if (ci[1] < mu & ci[2] > mu) 
+     hits <- hits + 1
+ }
> hits/nsim
[1] 0.94738
```

In terms of coverage, you're thus not doing any big mistake by relying on this interval.

You can get a mostly shorter interval with exact coverage, however, by constructing the interval from the smallest and largest observations $X_{(1)}$ and $X_{(n)}$.  These are sufficient statistics for $a$ and $b$.  It follows that
$$
Z_1=\frac{\frac{X_{(1)} + X_{(n)}}2-\frac{a+b}2}{X_{(n)}-X_{(1)}} \tag{1}
$$
is a [pivotal quantity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pivotal_quantity) since the distribution of $Z_1$ doesn't depend on $a$ and $b$, only $n$.  This follows because we alternatively can write (1) as
$$
Z_1=\frac{U_{(1)} + U_{(n)}-1}{2(U_{(n)}-U_{(1)})} \tag{2}
$$
where $U_{(1)}$ and $U_{(n)}$ denote the corresponding order statistics associated with $n$ observations from a uniform distribution on (0,1).

The joint density of $U_{(1)}$ and $U_{(n)}$ is
$$
f_{U_{(1)},U_{(n)}}(u_1,u_n)=n(n-1)(u_n-u_1)^{n-2}.
$$
for $0<u_1<u_n<1$.

Letting
$$
Z_2 = U_{(n)}-U_{(1)},
$$
the joint density of $Z_1,Z_2$ is
\begin{align}
f_{Z_1,Z_2}(z_1,z_2)
  &=f_{U_{(1)},U_{(n)}}(u_1(z_1,z_2),u_n(z_1,z_2))\left|\begin{matrix}\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial z_1} & \frac{\partial u_1}{\partial z_2} \\ \frac{\partial u_n}{\partial z_1} & \frac{\partial u_n}{\partial z_2}\end{matrix}\right|
\\&=n(n-1)z_2^{n-2}\left|\begin{matrix}z_2 & z_1 -\frac12 \\ z_2 & z_1 +\frac12\end{matrix}\right|
\\&=n(n-1)z_2^{n-1},
\end{align}
for $-\infty<z_1<\infty$ and $0<z_2<\frac1{2|z_1|+1}$. Elsewhere the density is zero.  Hence, the density of the pivot $Z_1$ is
$$
f_{Z_1}(z_1)=\int_0^{\frac1{2|z_1|+1}}f_{Z_1,Z_2}(z_1,z_2)dz_2=\frac{n-1}{(2|z_1|+1)^n}.
$$
Further calculations shows that the upper $\alpha/2$-quantile of this symmetric distribution is given by
$$
q_{\alpha/2} = \frac12\left( \alpha^{-\frac1{n-1}} - 1 \right).
$$
Inverting the double inequality involving (1), an exact $(1-\alpha)$ confidence interval for the mean $(a+b)/2$ is thus
$$
\frac{X_{(1)}+X_{(n)}}2 \pm \frac{X_{(n)}-X_{(1)}}2\left( \alpha^{-\frac1{n-1}} - 1 \right).
$$

Further simulations shows that the length of the exact interval indeed is considerably shorter:

```
> l1 <- l2 <- numeric(nsim)
> hits2 <- 0
> n <- 10
> pm <- c(-1,1)
> for (i in 1:nsim) {
+   x <- runif(n, a, b)
+   ci <- confint(lm(x ~ 1))
+   l1[i] <- ci[2]-ci[1]
+   ci2 <- (min(x)+max(x))/2 + pm*(max(x)-min(x))/2*(1/0.05^(1/(n-1))-1)
+   l2[i] <- ci2[2]-ci2[1]
+   if (ci[1] < mu & ci[2] > mu) 
+     hits <- hits + 1
+   if (ci2[1] < mu & ci2[2] > mu) 
+     hits2 <- hits2 + 1
+ }
> hits2/nsim
[1] 0.94917
> mean(l1)
[1] 0.407362
> mean(l2)
[1] 0.3230234
```