# Distribution of $F_n^{-1}(3/4)-F_n^{-1}(1/4)$

Tags: distributions, self-study, mathematical-statistics, quantiles, estimators

Given $X_1,X_2,...X_n\overset{\text{iid}}{\sim}F$, find the distribution of the sample inter quartile range, $F_n^{-1}(3/4)-F_n^{-1}(1/4)$ in terms of $F$ where, $F_n$ is the emperical distribution function defined as $F_n(x)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_i^n\mathbb{I}[X_i\le x]$ and $F^{-1}(t):=\inf\{x:F(x)\ge t\}$.

---

**Theorem.** For a random sample of size $n$ from an infinite population having value $x$ and density $f(x)$, the probability density at the $r$th order statistic $Y_{(r)}$ is given by
$$g_r(y)=\frac{n!}{(r-1)!(n-r)!}\left[\int_{-\infty}^y f(x)dx\right]^{r-1}f(y)\left[\int_y^\infty f(x)dx\right]^{n-r}$$
In terms of $F$, I can rewrite $$g_r(y)=r{n\choose r}~[F(y)]^{(r-1)}~F'(y)~[1-F(y)]^{(n-r)}$$

If I use this to find the distribution of $Y_{(r)}$, I get
$$G_r(y)=r{n\choose r}\int_{-\infty}^y[F(x)]^{(r-1)}~[1-F(x)]^{(n-r)}~dF(x)$$
For the $1/4$th quantile, I simply set $r=\lfloor n/4\rfloor$ where, $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$ denotes the greatest integer function. Similarly, for the other end.

---

The final expression using this method isn't "nice-looking". I was wondering if there is an error in this method, or if there is an alternative method that results in a simpler form.

**UPDATE.** (From @JarleTufto 's comment)

Joint density of $r,s$th quantiles
$$g_{r,s}(y_r,y_s)=\frac{n!}{(r-1)!(s-r-1)!(n-r)!}[F(y_r)]^{(r-1)}[F(y_s)-F(y_r)]^{s-r-1}[1-F(y_s)]^{(n-s)}F'(y_r)F'(y_s)$$ for $y_r\le y_s$. Transforming these to $Z_1=Y_r,Z_2=Y_s-Y_r$ we have joint density of $Z_1,Z_2$
$$f_{Z_1,Z_2}(z_1,z_2)=\frac{n!}{(r-1)!(s-r-1)!(n-r)!}[F(z_1)]^{(r-1)}[F(z_1+z_2)-F(z_1)]^{s-r-1}[1-F(z_1+z_2)]^{(n-s)}F'(z_1)F'(z_1+z_2)$$
for $z_2\ge0$.
WE find the marginal distribution of $Z_2$ as
$$f_{Z_2}(z)=\frac{n!}{(r-1)!(s-r-1)!(n-r)!}\int_{-\infty}^\infty [F(t)]^{(r-1)}[F(t+z)-F(t)]^{s-r-1}[1-F(t+z)]^{(n-s)}F'(t)F'(t+z)dt.$$
For IQR, we simply use $r=\lfloor n/4\rfloor,s=\lfloor 3n/4\rfloor$.

Comment: The sample quantiles defined via the generalised inverse of the empirical cdf are identical to two of the order statistics.  These are not independent but has a joint pdf (assuming that $F$ is continuous) given by https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic#The_joint_distribution_of_the_order_statistics_of_an_absolutely_continuous_distribution.  From that you may be able to derive the density of the interquartile range using methods similar to e.g. https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/352879/77222

Comment: To be a bit more specific, the empirical $\alpha$-quantile $F_n^{-1}(\alpha)=X_{(\lceil n\alpha\rceil)}$.

Comment: @JarleTufto please correct me if I am wrong: the method I mentioned only works in the case of finding the distribution of a single quantile, for example median. But, if were to find the distribution of the difference of two quantiles, I need to consider and use the joint distribution? (makes sense that they're not independent, missed that)

Comment: Yes, that's correct

Comment: Based on Jarle Tufto's comment, it seems you have already made the correct assessment of the problem. Is it so? Or are there still any query left here @zaira?

Comment: @User1865345 I have written the final form from my understanding of Jarle Tufto's comment. Is it correct?

Comment: Hello @zaira. The technique seems correct (based on the generic way to find distribution of transformed variables). I haven't followed it thoroughly though, but a quick look seems to suggest you might have done correctly. I will re-check once I get free.